# Fedora 32 terminal alert volume too loud

Tags: fedora, terminal

I recently upgraded my laptop to Fedora 32. After the upgrade the system alert in the terminal is unbearably loud. Other system alerts are fine and follow the overall volume settings. The issue is only in the terminal.
I have tried alsa mixer and PulseAudio Volume control.

How do I set the gain on terminal alerts?

Comment: Which terminal? ... xterm? ... gnome-terminal? ... etc.?  Which desktop environment and window manager are you using?